# How can I store data/string in Roku TV app?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want to implement token based login, So I need to store Auth token to verify the login session.

Please provide any solution. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this API

https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifregistrysection.md

You should use it inside Task-node nowadays, so it will get asynchronous. You can store any serialized data with your key in your section. It doesn't collide with other apps, since you are using your own Dev Key.

Comment: I store data successfully. But Is there any way or solution to Its store successfully or not.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question

Comment: I Explain I store two textbox data using a key in a roRegistrySection. But I don't know Its stored or not in Device. How to Check it datastore successfully in Roku Device

Comment: https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifregistrysection.md#existskey-as-string-as-boolean

Just check if it exists...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample for set and get userToken:

```
Function GetAuthData() As Dynamic
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
 if sec.Exists("UserRegistrationToken")
     return sec.Read("UserRegistrationToken")
 endif
 return invalid
End Function

Function SetAuthData(userToken As String) As Void
  sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
  sec.Write("UserRegistrationToken", userToken)
  sec.Flush()
End Function
```